# LRUCache returns size 0 until all images have been cached

Tags: java, android, caching, android-recyclerview, android-lru-cache

I'm using LRUCache to cache images that I retrieve from a server. I'm requesting them from a RecyclerView but till all the images are cached the LRUCache instance returns size 0.

Here's the **Code**

```
public void buildCache() {
        for (Feed feed : mFeeds) {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
            users.add(feed.getAuthor());
            try {
                if (feed.getPostType() == Feed.PostType.Collab) {
                    for (User receiver : feed.getUsers())
                        users.add(receiver);
                    getImages(users);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cache size: " + imagesLruCache.size());
                } else if (feed.getPostType() == Feed.PostType.Search){
                    String receiverUsername = feed.getReceiver().getUsername();
                    getImages(users);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        mCacheBuildingInterface.OnCacheBuilt();
        dataSetChanged();
}
```

What should I do to fix the problem ?
Thx to everyone

Comment: A) Why not use [`LruCache`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)? A `SoftReference` does not know wether it was recently used or not so the garbage collector does a terrible job at collecting the "right" thing (It's typically just collecting all soft references at once, thus wiping your cache). SoftReferences are no good cache. B) if your cache returns only `null` maybe it'a point A)

Comment: C) SoftReferenceCache#toString() clears the cache (`it.remove()`) D)  You're using picasso which has it's own (working) cache implementation. I'd honestly just get rid of all your manual caching attempts.

Comment: Thx for your advice @zapl . I've just updated the code, and now I'm using the LRUCache that's working like a charm. The only problem is still the first images that are not loading.

Comment: @zapl in the end I succed to use the Picasso caching service and it's working like a charm, thx for you advice again